# css3 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d and relative/absolute elements flickering

Tags: google-chrome, css, webkit

I have an issue with `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;`

Any elements that are children of an element with this style (that are positioned relative or absolute) dont show and when a transform takes place I can see the element in the background flicker.

If I remove `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;` the element displays fine.

Anyone else come up against this?

(I will try and get a jsfiddle in place asap)

Ad.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Chrome. Nothing to be done about it except wait for it to be fixed.

Comment: Can you cite your source for this?  I'm having the same issue and would love to investigate further.